# Android - Unfortunately, Camera has stopped - Default Camera

Tags: android, windows, webcam

I am trying to create an Android virtual machine to test out some camera applications. When I start the AVD with the configuration options shown below I normally receive the 'Unfortunately, Camera has stopped.' error. Sometimes, the camera app actually works though. This is the default camera app in the emulator.

My AVD specifications:

[image: Picture of AVD]

Here is the text of the AVD specifications if the picture is not available:

```
Device: 5.4" FWVGA (480 X 854: mdpi)
Target: Android 5.0.1 - API Level 21
CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)
Keyboard: (checked) Hardware keyboard present 
Skin: No skin
Front Camera: None 
Back Camera: Webcam0
Memory Options: RAM:512 VM Heap:16
Internal Storage: 200 MiB
SD Card: Size 200 MiB
File: [blank]
Emulation Options: (unchecked) Snapshot (checked) Use Host GPU
```

Here is a picture of the error I receive when the camera fails to start:

[image]

If you cannot see the pic of the screen capture the error window says, "Unfortunately, Camera has stopped".

When the application does not work I see the following box:

[image]

When the camera application actually functions the emulator starts up with the webcam light also on and does not ask me to select which webcam.

When the camera does not work these interesting lines in the log are displayed:

```
01-23 10:32:08.324: V/CameraHolder(1033): open camera 0
01-23 10:32:08.334: E/CameraService(65): CameraService::connect X (pid 1033)   rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
01-23 10:32:08.339: W/CameraBase(1033): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033): fail to connect Camera
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:497)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:342)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-23 10:32:08.409: E/CameraHolder(1033): --------- beginning of crash
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-112
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Process: com.android.camera, PID: 1033
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): java.lang.RuntimeException: openCamera failed
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:272)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.camera.Camera$4.run(Camera.java:1100)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Caused by: com.android.camera.CameraHardwareException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to  connect to camera service
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:135)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.camera.Util.openCamera(Util.java:267)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     ... 2 more
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:497)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:342)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.camera.CameraHolder.open(CameraHolder.java:131)
01-23 10:32:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     ... 3 more
01-23 10:32:08.448: W/ActivityManager(350):   Force finishing activity com.android.camera/.Camera
01-23 10:32:08.775: I/WindowManager(350): Screenshot max retries 4 of   Token{3946fe74 ActivityRecord{3ae28647 u0 com.android.camera/.Camera t25 f}}  appWin=Window{7b73fe3 u0 Starting com.android.camera} drawState=4
```

Does anyone know what is going on? I am on a Windows 7 operating-system.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Win7 x64, API level 22, Lollipop version.